# How do I fix the spectre v2 spectre mitigation lfence not serializing error?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, 64-bit

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 amd 64bit on Oracle VM Virtualbox and it just says Spectre V2 Spectre mitigation: lfence not serializing, switching to generic retpoline and just stops after that. I've tried searching around on google and haven't had much luck, mostly just to try 16.04 instead, I guess I can try that if necessary. If anyone has any knowledge of this please let me know.

Comment: Does this =>"just stops after that." mean that your computer does not successfully boot to the login screen?

Comment: Yes,it will not successfully boot,I can't begin installation or anything.

Comment: OK, I get that message sometimes, and the PC still boots. So your problem is not necessarily related to that message.